# In c# is there a way to use the Type class to declare a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

Is there a way to do the following?

```
Type v = typeof(string);
MyClass<v> myClass = new MyClass<v>();
```

It would be used in the following context:

```
interface MyClassInterface
{
  Type GetType();
}

class MyClass<T> : MyClassInterface
{
  Type GetType()
  {
    return typeof(T);
  }
}
```

....in Main:

```
List<MyClassInterface> list;


foreach(MyClassInterface class in list)
{
  Type type = class.GetType();
  List<type> list = new List<type>();
}
```

I do not want to declare it of type "object".

Many thanks. Apologies if this is answered somewhere else. I have no idea this is called... "How to keep your Generic generic?"

Comment: Why does this have a java tag?

Comment: what is your goal through this ? do you want to create instance dynamically ?

Comment: Have you considered the technique described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590540/c-declaring-and-using-a-list-of-generic-classes-with-different-types-how?rq=1?

Comment: That link is a nice workaround. Thanks all.